# Two signer issue in docusign embedded signing for same envelope one after another

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to get 2 user signed with docusign embedded sign. I'm using the example code given by Docusign/github. I'd like that the second user, see that the first user has signed the document so, based ob some explanation here, I try to get the envelope id, when the first signer has signed the document, but i obtain an error. It seems that there is something wrong in the second recipient. Someone would help?

```
$username_docusign=$config['username_docusign'];
$password_docusign=$config['password_docusign'];
$integrator_key_docusign=$config['integrator_key_docusign'];
$host_docusign=$config['host_docusign'];
// create a new DocuSign configuration and assign host and header(s)
$config = new DocuSign\eSign\Configuration();
$config->setSSLVerification(false);
$config->setHost($host_docusign);
$config->addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", "{\"Username\":\"" . $username_docusign . "\",\"Password\":\"" . $password_docusign . "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" . $integrator_key_docusign . "\"}");
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1:  Login() API
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// instantiate a new docusign api client
$apiClient = new DocuSign\eSign\ApiClient($config);


// we will first make the Login() call which exists in the AuthenticationApi...
$authenticationApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi($apiClient);
// optional login parameters
$options = new \DocuSign\eSign\Api\AuthenticationApi\LoginOptions();
// call the login() API
$loginInformation = $authenticationApi->login($options);



// parse the login results
if(isset($loginInformation) && count($loginInformation) > 0)
{
// note: defaulting to first account found, user might be a 
// member of multiple accounts
$loginAccount = $loginInformation->getLoginAccounts()[0];
if(isset($loginInformation))
{
    $accountId = $loginAccount->getAccountId();
    if(!empty($accountId))
    {
        echo "Account ID = $accountId\n";
    }
}
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2:  Create & Send Envelope with Embedded Recipient
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// set recipient information
$recipientName = "user1";
$recipientEmail = "sanjaydas2390@gmail.com";
// configure the document we want signed



$recipientName2 = "user2";
$recipientEmail2 = "dassanjay5313@gmail.com";

$documentFileName = "hhhh.pdf";
$documentName = "hhhh.pdf";

$demo_docs_path      = __DIR__ . '/demo_documents/';


// instantiate a new envelopeApi object
$envelopeApi = new DocuSign\eSign\Api\EnvelopesApi($apiClient);
// Add a document to the envelope
$document = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document();
$document->setDocumentBase64(base64_encode(file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . 'World_Wide_Corp_fields.pdf')));
$document->setName($documentName);
$document->setDocumentId("1");
// Create a |SignHere| tab somewhere on the document for the recipient to sign
$signHere = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();

$signHere->setAnchorString("Sign here user1");//here my text in html
$signHere->setAnchorXOffset("3");
$signHere->setAnchorYOffset("0");
$signHere->setAnchorUnits("inches");
$signHere->setPageNumber("1");
$signHere->setRecipientId("1");
// add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere));
// add a signer to the envelope
$signer = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
$signer->setEmail($recipientEmail);
$signer->setName($recipientName);
$signer->setRecipientId("1");
$signer->setTabs($tabs);
$signer->setClientUserId('12345');

$signHere2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere();

$signHere2->setAnchorString("Sign here user2");//here my text in html
$signHere2->setAnchorXOffset("3");
$signHere2->setAnchorYOffset("0");
$signHere2->setAnchorUnits("inches");
$signHere2->setPageNumber("1");
$signHere2->setRecipientId("2");
// add the signature tab to the envelope's list of tabs
$tabs2 = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs();
$tabs2->setSignHereTabs(array($signHere2));
// add a signer to the envelope
$signer2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer();
$signer2->setEmail($recipientEmail2);
$signer2->setName($recipientName2);
$signer2->setRecipientId("2");
$signer2->setTabs($tabs2);
$signer2->setClientUserId('123456');





// must set this to embed the recipient!
// Add a recipient to sign the document
$recipients = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients();
$recipients->setSigners(array($signer),array($signer2) );
$envelop_definition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition();
$envelop_definition->setEmailSubject("oggetto mail");
// set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
$envelop_definition->setStatus("sent");
$envelop_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
$envelop_definition->setDocuments(array($document));
// create and send the envelope! (aka signature request)
$envelop_summary = $envelopeApi->createEnvelope($accountId, $envelop_definition, null);

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 3:  Request Recipient View (aka signing URL)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// instantiate a RecipientViewRequest object
$recipient_view_request = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest();
// set where the recipient is re-directed once they are done signing
$recipient_view_request->setReturnUrl("http://localhost/docusign/index.php?enevelope=".$envelop_summary->getEnvelopeId());
// configure the embedded signer 
if ($_GET['enevelope']=="") {

$recipient_view_request->setUserName($recipientName);
$recipient_view_request->setEmail($recipientEmail);
// must reference the same clientUserId that was set for the recipient when they 
// were added to the envelope in step 2
$recipient_view_request->setClientUserId('12345');
// used to indicate on the certificate of completion how the user authenticated
$recipient_view_request->setAuthenticationMethod("email");
// generate the recipient view! (aka embedded signing URL)
$signingView = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountId, $envelop_summary->getEnvelopeId(), $recipient_view_request);
$signurl= $signingView->getUrl();

} else {


$recipient_view_request1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\RecipientViewRequest();
// set where the recipient is re-directed once they are done signing
$recipient_view_request1->setReturnUrl("http://localhost/docusign/index.php?enevelope=100");

 $recipient_view_request1->setUserName($recipientName2);
$recipient_view_request1->setEmail($recipientEmail2);
// must reference the same clientUserId that was set for the recipient when they 
// were added to the envelope in step 2
$recipient_view_request1->setClientUserId('123456');
// used to indicate on the certificate of completion how the user authenticated
$recipient_view_request1->setAuthenticationMethod("email");
// generate the recipient view! (aka embedded signing URL)

$signingView = $envelopeApi->createRecipientView($accountId, $_GET['enevelope'], $recipient_view_request1);
$signurl= $signingView->getUrl();

}
header('Location: '.$signurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, not sure what sample code you used, but this code you pasted here is using the old/legacy authentication. I highly recommend you use our modern/new oauth. You can find examples for that in this page - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples.
In terms of having 2 recipients sign sequentially, you would have to use what we call "routing order". If you specify a routingOrder parameter on the recipient, DocuSign would route the envelope based on this number (from low to high). So if your first recipient is "1" and second is "2" then the second recipient would only see the envelope after the first one signed it.

Comment: pasted below as another answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Creates envelope definition
     * Document 1: An HTML document.
     * Document 2: A Word .docx document.
     * Document 3: A PDF document.
     * DocuSign will convert all of the documents to the PDF format.
     * The recipients' field tags are placed using <b>anchor</b> strings.
     * @param $args parameters for the envelope:
     *              signer_email, signer_name, signer_client_id
     * @return mixed -- returns an envelope definition
     */
    private function make_envelope($args)
    {
        # document 1 (html) has sign here anchor tag **signature_1**
        # document 2 (docx) has sign here anchor tag /sn1/
        # document 3 (pdf)  has sign here anchor tag /sn1/
        #
        # The envelope has two recipients.
        # recipient 1 - signer
        # recipient 2 - cc
        # The envelope will be sent first to the signer.
        # After it is signed, a copy is sent to the cc person.
        #
        # create the envelope definition
        $envelope_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
           'email_subject' => 'Please sign this document set'
        ]);
        $doc1_b64 = base64_encode($this->create_document1($args));
        # read files 2 and 3 from a local directory
        # The reads could raise an exception if the file is not available!
        $demo_docs_path = __DIR__ . '/../public/demo_documents/';
        $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['doc_docx']);
        $doc2_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);
        $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['doc_pdf']);
        $doc3_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);
        # Create the document models
        $document1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
            'document_base64' => $doc1_b64,
            'name' => 'Order acknowledgement',  # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'html',  # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => '1'  # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);
        $document2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
            'document_base64' => $doc2_b64,
            'name' => 'Battle Plan',  # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'docx',  # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => '2'  # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);
        $document3 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
            'document_base64' => $doc3_b64,
            'name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',  # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => '3'  # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);
        # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
        $envelope_definition->setDocuments([$document1, $document2, $document3]);
        # Create the signer recipient model
        $signer1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
            'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
            'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"]);
        # routingOrder (lower means earlier) determines the order of deliveries
        # to the recipients. Parallel routing order is supported by using the
        # same integer as the order for two or more recipients.
        # create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents
        $cc1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\CarbonCopy([
            'email' => $args['cc_email'], 'name' => $args['cc_name'],
            'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2"]);
        # Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
        # We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
        #
        # The DocuSign platform searches throughout your envelope's
        # documents for matching anchor strings. So the
        # signHere2 tab will be used in both document 2 and 3 since they
        #  use the same anchor string for their "signer 1" tabs.
        $sign_here1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'anchor_string' => '**signature_1**', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20']);
        $sign_here2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
            'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 'anchor_units' =>  'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20']);
        # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tabs) to the signer
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $signer1->setTabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs([
            'sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here1, $sign_here2]]));
        # Add the recipients to the envelope object
        $recipients = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients([
            'signers' => [$signer1], 'carbon_copies' => [$cc1]]);
        $envelope_definition->setRecipients($recipients);
        # Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
        # To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
        $envelope_definition->setStatus($args["status"]);
        return $envelope_definition;
    }
    /**
     * Creates a customized html document for the envelope
     * @param args $
     * @return string -- the html document
     */
    private function create_document1($args)
    {
        return <<< heredoc
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
        </head>
        <body style="font-family:sans-serif;margin-left:2em;">
        <h1 style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: darkblue;margin-bottom: 0;">World Wide Corp</h1>
        <h2 style="font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 3.5em;font-size: 1em;
color: darkblue;">Order Processing Division</h2>
        <h4>Ordered by {$args['signer_name']}</h4>
        <p style="margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;">Email: {$args['signer_email']}</p>
        <p style="margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;">Copy to: {$args['cc_name']}, {$args['cc_email']}</p>
        <p style="margin-top:3em;">
  Candy bonbon pastry jujubes lollipop wafer biscuit biscuit. Topping brownie sesame snaps sweet roll pie. Croissant danish biscuit soufflé caramels jujubes jelly. Dragée danish caramels lemon drops dragée. Gummi bears cupcake biscuit tiramisu sugar plum pastry. Dragée gummies applicake pudding liquorice. Donut jujubes oat cake jelly-o. Dessert bear claw chocolate cake gummies lollipop sugar plum ice cream gummies cheesecake.
        </p>
        <!-- Note the anchor tag for the signature field is in white. -->
        <h3 style="margin-top:3em;">Agreed: <span style="color:white;">**signature_1**/</span></h3>
        </body>
    </html>
heredoc;
    }
```